# In Javascript verify is var is valid datetime object

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to verify is var is valid datetime object.
This

```
alert( "dat::"+( typeof dat ))
```

returns "object".
 Which is the valid way ?

Comment: Hi,
if you think my answer is the one that you were looking for, plz consider accepting it by clicking on the hallow checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

```
if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(d) === "[object Date]" ) {
  // it is a date
}
else {
  // not a date
}
```

Comment: Not sure it's possible for *getTime* to return NaN, unless it's the *Date.prototype* object or it's deliberately set to NaN. So why the second test?

Comment: Well you're right (I should have thought this through), maybe I can just remove the second test.

Comment: I think the first test is sufficient and as reliable as is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
dat instanceof Date
```

Comment: That will not work across frames. *instanceof* looks to see if the constructor's prototype is on the object's internal `[[Prototype]]` chain. That doesn't happen across frames since different Date constructors (and hence *Date.prototype* objects) are used.